# How to update ubuntu remote git server repository?

Tags: git, ubuntu

I had set up the git repository in Ubuntu server. 
When i push data into the server `git push`, its successfully pushed. And i can see that changes by user if i do new **`git clone`** or update using **`git pull`**. But i am not finding that code or file changes in Ubuntu server repository. What can be the possible problem?

e.g. `git clone remote-server` , giving all the updated changes. but in remote-server repo that changes are not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats miserable what version of ubuntu you are using ?i feel some dependencies was missed out while installing git.

try

$ :sudo apt-get update
$ :sudo apt-get upgrade
$ :sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext unzip

after this follow installation for git.

Comment: I tried this but everything is working fine but i am not able to find source code on my server.

Comment: @HiteshVaghani : what version of ubuntu you are using ?